# Big problem accessing USB with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

System is Acer Laptop, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 terminal

Halfway through installing an application and I cant seem to access any of the USBs. LSUSB just completes and returns nothing. Typically I'm doing a project and this could stop it in its tracks.

Any help you could give would be much appreciated

Edit: using lower case `lsusb`:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for those looking at a similar issue in the future, a solution from Arnaud.

The Ubuntu 16.04 installation I used was the Windows subsystem for linux version. As of 20.6.2018 they have not implemented any USB functionality on this version and so I was unable to look at any USB details or use the lsusb command.